# how to get header files from CoreTelephony.framework for telephone control api

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to develop an iphone re-dialer application, for that coretelephony.framework is needed as it contains required telephone control api. But i'm unable to class-dump headers of coretelephony.framework as it is C headers. 
Can anybody help me to dump headers of coretelephony framework?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 18):

CoreTelephony framework contains four files only. so you can import these classes as follow:

```
#import<CoreTelephony/CTCallCenter.h>    
#import<CoreTelephony/CTCall.h>   
#import<CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>    
#import<CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>
```

hope it will help!!